# Nginx drop request body

Tags: nginx

Can nginx drop request body?
As the vulnerability if log4j.
I would be like to drop the request body for some request. The system is on-going, that can't apply xhanges immediately. So I trying whether nginx can help.
I tried proxy_set_body, but do not work.

Comment: Slightly unrelated to your question since you may be running the free version, but you may want to take a look at https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-log4j-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228-with-nginx/ for some more official nginx guidance on mitigating the log4j problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ModSecurity](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-nginx) to filter requests.